# Flash message is not showing up when Inherited_resource gem used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inherited-resources

When I use the default IC action in my controller like this:

```
    def update
      update!(:notice => "Order has been updated."){edit_sales_order_path(@sales_order)}
    end
```

the notice doesn't show up in my json response. But if I overwrite the action like this, it works.

```
    if @sales_order.update_attributes(permitted_params[:sales_order])
      flash[:notice] = "Order has been updated"
    else
```

Any idea?